# Can I use PKCS#11 to create a signature in a HSM?

Tags: java, pkcs#11, xades4j

Can I configure XAdES4J to **delegate the signature creation** to a hardware-security-module (HSM) using a PKCS#11 infrastructure? If yes - how?

Infos on these sites let me assume, that only a key-transfer using PKCS#11 is possible:

- https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/DefiningKeyingData (the terms keying-data, -provider)
- http://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/QeA (discussion of onur)
- http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/providers/impl/KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.html (Step 3: "Return the entry's private key")

Comment: downvotes should have a comment with reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previously stated, you can use PKCS#11 keying data by using PKCS11KeyingDataProvider. You just need to configure it with the native PKCS#11 lib of your HSM.

The `PrivateKey` interface is just a marker interface for opaque key representations. When your using the PKCS#11 provider, returned `PrivateKey` instances are just handles (representatives) of the key, since the key material doesn't actually leave the HSM. The signature engine will be selected using delayed provider selection, accordingly to the `PrivateKey` provider, since this provider is the one that knows how to handle that specific `PrivateKey`. In this case, both the key and the signature value calculation are fully handled by the HSM.

XAdES4j's `PKCS11KeyingDataProvider` is just a wrapper around a Java `KeyStore` created from a specific PKCS#11 provider instance which is configured with the supplied native lib path.

Answer (score 1):

Simple browsing brought me to:

https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/DefiningKeyingData

There's a section about PKCS#11 there. Does that not work for you?

Comment: The info on the pointed wiki page should be enough. In addition, check the java docs for the PKCS11KeyingDataProvider (http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/providers/impl/PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.html).

Comment: It seemed to me that only key-transfer is possible, not signature creation in a crypto-module. I rephrased my question. **is signature creation within a HSM possible?**  (i.e. the application does not know about the private key)